# How to reuse code inside sdf format of a model in gazebo to write bigger models?

Tags: gazebo, sdformat, gazebo-11, gazebo-model, xml

I am building a bigger model in sdf for gazebo. I have many similar links with only variation in their pose and all other parameters are same. Is there any way to reuse code of the links ?

I have provided a code snippet below. The links 1 to 5 are getting repeated. Ideally I want to make 100s of them in the code and I do not want to code paste the same thing and change it's position. Please let me know a better way to do it ?

false

```
<!-- pole1 -->
<link name="pole1">
<pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
<velocity_decay>
<angular>0.05</angular>
</velocity_decay>
  <inertial>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>0041.7</ixx>
      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
      <iyy>0041.7</iyy>
      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
      <izz>2.5e-02</izz>
   </inertia>
    <mass>10.0</mass>
  </inertial>
  
  <collision name="collision">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>1.0</length>
        <radius>0.05</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  
  <visual name="visual">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>1.0</length>
        <radius>0.05</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script><uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri><name>Gazebo/Red</name></script>
    </material>
  </visual>
</link>
    
<!-- link1 -->
<link name="link1">
<pose>0 0.1 0.5 1.5707 0 0</pose>
<velocity_decay>
<angular>0.05</angular>
</velocity_decay>
  <inertial>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>0.0417</ixx>
      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
      <iyy>0.0417</iyy>
      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
      <izz>2.5e-05</izz>
   </inertia>
    <mass>0.01</mass>
  </inertial>
  
  <collision name="collision">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>0.2</length>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  
  <visual name="visual">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>0.2</length>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script><uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri><name>Gazebo/Black</name></script>
    </material>
  </visual>
</link>

<!-- link2 -->
<link name="link2">
<pose>0 0.3 0.5 1.5707 0 0</pose>
<velocity_decay>
<angular>0.05</angular>
</velocity_decay>
  <inertial>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>0.0417</ixx>
      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
      <iyy>0.0417</iyy>
      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
      <izz>2.5e-05</izz>
   </inertia>
    <mass>0.01</mass>
  </inertial>
  
  <collision name="collision">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>0.2</length>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  
  <visual name="visual">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>0.2</length>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script><uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri><name>Gazebo/Black</name></script>
    </material>
  </visual>    
</link>

<!-- link3 -->
<link name="link3">
<pose>0 0.5 0.5 1.5707 0 0</pose>
<velocity_decay>
<angular>0.05</angular>
</velocity_decay>
  <inertial>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>0.0417</ixx>
      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
      <iyy>0.0417</iyy>
      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
      <izz>2.5e-05</izz>
   </inertia>
    <mass>0.01</mass>
  </inertial>
  
  <collision name="collision">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>0.2</length>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  
  <visual name="visual">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>0.2</length>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script><uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri><name>Gazebo/Black</name></script>
    </material>
  </visual>    
</link>

<!-- link4 -->
<link name="link4">
<pose>0 0.7 0.5 1.5707 0 0</pose>
<velocity_decay>
<angular>0.05</angular>
</velocity_decay>
  <inertial>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>0.0417</ixx>
      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
      <iyy>0.0417</iyy>
      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
      <izz>2.5e-05</izz>
   </inertia>
    <mass>0.01</mass>
  </inertial>
  
  <collision name="collision">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>0.2</length>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  
  <visual name="visual">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>0.2</length>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script><uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri><name>Gazebo/Black</name></script>
    </material>
  </visual>    
</link>

<!-- link5 -->
<link name="link5">
<pose>0 0.9 0.5 1.5707 0 0</pose>
<velocity_decay>
<angular>0.05</angular>
</velocity_decay>
  <inertial>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>0.0417</ixx>
      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
      <iyy>0.0417</iyy>
      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
      <izz>2.5e-05</izz>
   </inertia>
    <mass>0.01</mass>
  </inertial>
  
  <collision name="collision">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>0.2</length>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  
  <visual name="visual">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>0.2</length>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script><uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri><name>Gazebo/Black</name></script>
    </material>
  </visual>    
</link>              

<!-- pole2 -->
<link name="pole2">
<pose>0 1.0 0 0 0 0</pose>
<velocity_decay>
<angular>0.05</angular>
</velocity_decay>
  <inertial>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>0041.7</ixx>
      <ixy>0.0</ixy>
      <ixz>0.0</ixz>
      <iyy>0041.7</iyy>
      <iyz>0.0</iyz>
      <izz>2.5e-02</izz>
   </inertia>
    <mass>10.0</mass>
  </inertial>
  
  <collision name="collision">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>1.0</length>
        <radius>0.05</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  
  <visual name="visual">
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <length>1.0</length>
        <radius>0.05</radius>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script><uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri><name>Gazebo/Red</name></script>
    </material>
  </visual>
</link>

<!--pole1 and link1 joint attachment -->
<joint type="revolute" name="pole1_hinge">
  <pose>0 0 0.1 0 0 0</pose>
  <child>link1</child>
  <parent>pole1</parent>
  <axis>
    <use_parent_model_frame>true</use_parent_model_frame>
    <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
  </axis>
</joint>  

<!-- link1 and link2 joint attachment -->
<joint type="revolute" name="link12_hinge">
  <pose>0 0 0.1 0 0 0</pose>
  <child>link2</child>
  <parent>link1</parent>
  <axis>
    <use_parent_model_frame>true</use_parent_model_frame>
    <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
  </axis>
</joint> 

<!-- link2 and link3 joint attachment -->
<joint type="revolute" name="link23_hinge">
  <pose>0 0 0.1 0 0 0</pose>
  <child>link3</child>
  <parent>link2</parent>
  <axis>
    <use_parent_model_frame>true</use_parent_model_frame>
    <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
  </axis>
</joint>

<!-- link3 and link4 joint attachment -->
<joint type="revolute" name="link34_hinge">
  <pose>0 0 0.1 0 0 0</pose>
  <child>link4</child>
  <parent>link3</parent>
  <axis>
    <use_parent_model_frame>true</use_parent_model_frame>
    <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
  </axis>
</joint>

<!-- link4 and link5 joint attachment -->
<joint type="revolute" name="link45_hinge">
  <pose>0 0 0.1 0 0 0</pose>
  <child>link5</child>
  <parent>link4</parent>
  <axis>
    <use_parent_model_frame>true</use_parent_model_frame>
    <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
  </axis>
</joint>                 

<!-- link5 and pole2 joint attachment -->
<joint type="revolute" name="pole2_hinge">
  <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
  <child>pole2</child>
  <parent>link5</parent>
  <axis>
    <use_parent_model_frame>true</use_parent_model_frame>
    <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
  </axis>
</joint>
```